# How to use Android setTranslation ? (or another way to move a textview ?)

Tags: java, android, textview

I want to start to make a "spirit level" app (not sure of this word, the tool to make sure the surface you put it on is even(straight)) for school.
For now I just want to move textviews then I'll had the sensor listener to do it automatically then i'll turn them to images, etc..

Anyway, I can't move the textView in the screen!

I found a method in view, called setTranslationX and setTranslationY who seem to do exactly what I want, so I tried to use them this way:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

float nombre=100;
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

TextView H = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Champ_H);

H.setTranslationX(nombre);
```

To just move a textView to the right.

But I've got this message for the last line:

> The method setTranslationX(float) is undefined for the type TextView

The problem is, yes, it is, I looked the documentation, this method exists and takes a float as a parameter.
I've of course imported android.view.View which is supposed to contain it, but that won't work.
I've also tried to use setLeft which does a similar thing but the same problem occurs. It seems that every method what would allow me to move a textView, eclipse won't let me use them.

Does anybody know why?
Or know an other way to move a TextView?

Comment: What is the target and min API level of your project (android:targetSdkVersion and android:minSdkVersion in the manifest file)? In the documentation of the setTranslationX method: "Added in API level 11".

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that. I thought about that but didn't see specifications about API in the doc. I used API 7 because a tutorial I followed used this.
I'm installing the newest API right now, that will probably work.

Thank you !

Comment: Let me know if it works. In that case I can convert my comment to a proper answer for you to accept, to makr your question as solved.

Answer (score 3):

Use `nineOldAndroid.jar` file in your project And use this way

```
import com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper;


ViewHelper.setTranslationX(myView, translation);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
h.setTranslationX(100f);
```

in my eclipse is work fine:)

Comment: in which android version you write? (API level)

Comment: I used API 7 but I just read TofferJ comment that tells I have to use at least 11, that will probably work that way, thanks

Answer (score -3):

You may need to specify the unit to translate. try:

```
H.setTranslationX(100px);
```

see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:translationX